# Selecting word text in a for loop

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2007

I created this code to search through my word document and find the word APPENDIX3, and if found, delete it and the space before it (section break in this case). It then subtracts the number 3 by 1 and goes back to the top of the for loop and searches for APPENDIX2 and deletes the stuff I wanted. It loops through 3 times, ending at APPENDIX1. The only problem is that it only deletes the APPENDIX3 stuff. If I rerun the Macro it will delete APPENDIX2 and only APPENDIX2. On so on.  It is incrementing but the selection does not appear to be cleared. Any suggestions as to how I can modify my code to loop through and select different text each time?

```
Sub RemoveAppendices()
Dim i As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
'Cntr = 3
'For i = 1 To 3
For i=3 to 1 step -1
    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "APPENDIX" & Cntr
        If Selection.Find.Execute Then
            Selection.Select
            Selection.Delete
            With Selection
                .EndKey Unit:=wdStory
                .TypeBackspace
                .Delete
            End With
        End If
    End With
    'Cntr = Cntr - 1

Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: when deleting any part of collection you should run your loop from last item to first. Therefore try something like `For i=3 to 1 step -1`. Moreover, instead of `Cntr = Cntr -1` you could use `i`.

Comment: I modified code above to reflect your changes and it is indeed more efficient (so thank you), but the issue of clearing the initial text found and finding the next text value and running this selection through the If statement remains unsolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I needed to either go to the top of the page within the loop instead of before the loop, or I had to wrap the text search during find. Updated script looks like this:

```
Sub RemoveAppendices()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 3 To 1 Step -1
    'Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory 'this would also work but I like wrap better
    With Selection.Find
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Text = "APPENDIX" & i
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchCase = True
        If Selection.Find.Execute Then
            Selection.Select
            Selection.Delete
            With Selection
                .EndKey Unit:=wdStory
                .TypeBackspace
                .Delete
            End With
        End If
    End With
Next i
End Sub
```